# Going from ListFragment to Fragment using FragmentTransaction - can't go back to the ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I'll jump straight to the point.

I'm making an application with has three tabs (*MainFragment, FragmentCategories, FragmentList*). What I want to do next is this:

From the second tab, *FragmentCategories*, I open up a certain category. Using getFragmentManager and FragmentTransaction, I open up a *FragmentCategoriesList*. From there, when I choose a certain object, I want to open it in yet another "subfragment".

Following a number of tutorials, *MyFragmentCategoriesList* uses a ListView layout.

```
context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories_list, container, false);
```

Later in the code, I initialize a ListView object which uses that same layout **(R.layout.fragment_categories_list == R.id.frag_cat_list)**.

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_cat_list);**
lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(context, searchResults));
```

Here's a snippet where I select an object:

```
...
                data.putString("selection",test);
                FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentCategoriesDetail FragCatDetail = new FragmentCategoriesDetail();
                FragCatDetail.setArguments(data); 
                fragTrans.add(R.id.frag_cat, FragCatDetail);
                fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
                fragTrans.commit();
...
```

Anyway, the problem is this:

```
fragTrans.add(R.id.frag_cat, FragCatDetail);
```

In this case, my *FragCatDetail* works, but I can't go BACK to the *FragmentCategoriesList*. If I put **R.id.listview** (a relative layout xml containing two textviews), my Fragment opens WITHIN an object of a ListView, and I can go back to *FragmentCategoriesList*.

If I put **R.id.frag_cat_list** (which is, after all, the layout of the current fragment, *FragmentCategoriesList*), my app crashes with

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
```

which seems logical because *FragCatDetail* is a Fragment with a relative layout.

My question is this: what can I do in order to have my *FragCatDetail* fragment work like in the first case (relative layout) AND go back to *FragmentCategoriesList* like in the second case (listview layout).

Thanks in advance! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was the problem.

```
            FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragManager.beginTransaction();
            FragmentCategoriesDetail FragCatDetail = new FragmentCategoriesDetail();
            FragCatDetail.setArguments(data); 
            fragTrans.add(R.id.frag_cat, FragCatDetail);
            fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
            fragTrans.commit();
```

Throughout the application, I used 
`getFragmentManager().popBackStack()`. Since I was going to a new fragment (*FragmentCategoriesDetail*), I was doing that by getSupportFragmentManager.

In my Main Activity, I overrode *onBackPressed()* and inside I was using

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

where in fact I should have been using

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

at least for this specific fragment.

Once again, it is a story of a *FragmentManager* vs *SupportFragmentManager*. I hope I helped someone with this. :)